# Duplicate line and replace string

Tags: regex, xml, text, replace, grep

I have an XML file that contains more than 10,000 items. Each item contains a line like this.

`<g:id><![CDATA[FBM00101816_BLACK-L]]></g:id>`

For each item I need to add another line below like this:

`<sku><![CDATA[FBM00101816]]></sku>`

So I need to duplicate each **g:id** line, replace the **g:id** with **sku** and trim the value to delete all characters after the underscore (including it). The final result would be like this:

```
<g:id><![CDATA[FBM00101816_BLACK-L]]></g:id>
<sku><![CDATA[FBM00101816]]></sku>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So... what tools are you using?...

Comment: Just a code/text editor with grep capabilities. BBEdit to be precise.

Comment: I also have access to Oxygen XML editor but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Then this isn't really a programming question but a help me with my one-off regex problem kind of thing? i'd probably try something like this: ^(<g:id>)>([^_]+?)(.+)?</g:id>)$/g "$0\n<sku>{$3}</sku>" but I typed that as a comment without checking anything....

Comment: Yes, more a "help me" question... Thanks for your reply, there must be a typo but I will try to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after commenting, I couldn't help myself. This seemed to do what you asked for.

```
find: <g:id><!\[CDATA\[([^\_]+)?(.+)?\]></g:id>
replace: $0\n<sku><![CDATA[$1]></sku>
```

I don't have BBEdit, but this is what it looked like in Textmate:

[image]

Comment: Okay, so there is still at least one error in here, the second closing "]" character is missing in the replacement. I'm sure you can figure that out though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Chris, I only needed to change $0 to \0 etc in order to make this work with BBedit.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT, it's

```
<xsl:template match="g:id">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <sku><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '_')"/></sku>
</xsl:template>
```

Or using Saxon's Gizmo (https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!gizmo) it's

```
follow //g:id with <sku>{substring-before(., '_')}</sku>
```

Don't try to do this sort of thing in a text editor (or any other tool that doesn't involve a real XML parser) unless it's a one-off. Your code will be too sensitive to trivial variations in the way the source XML is written and will almost inevitably have bugs - which might not matter for a one-off, but do matter if it's going to be used repeatedly over a period of time.

Note also, the CDATA tags in your input (and output) are a waste of space. CDATA tags have no significance unless the element content includes special characters like `<` and `&`, which isn't the case in your examples.

Comment: All very true and exactly why I did verify it was a one-off. I don't usually like recommending regular expressions, but I do love me some regex puzzles ;-)